# Why can't http2 streams be reused?

Tags: http2

According to RFC7540:

> An HTTP request/response exchange fully consumes a single stream. A request starts with the HEADERS frame that puts the stream into an "open" state. The request ends with a frame bearing END_STREAM, which causes the stream to become "half-closed (local)" for the client and "half-closed (remote)" for the server. A response starts with a HEADERS frame and ends with a frame bearing END_STREAM, which places the stream in the "closed" state.

Knowing that a stream cannot be reopened once it's closed, this means that if I want to implement a long-lived connection where the client sends a stream of requests to the server, I will have to use a new stream for each request. But there is a finite number of streams available, so in theory, I could run out of streams and have to restart the connection.

Why did the writers of the specification design a request/response exchange to completely consume a stream? Wouldn't it have been easy to make a stream like a single thread of exchanges, where you can have multiple exchanges done in serial in one stream?

Answer (score 2):

The point of having many streams multiplexed in a single connection is to interleave them, so that if one cannot proceed, others can.

Reusing a stream for more than one request means just reusing its stream id. I don't see much benefit reusing 4-byte integers -- on the contrary the implementation would become quite more complicated.

For example, the server can inform the client of the last stream that it processed when it's about to close a connection. If stream ids are reused, it would not be possible to report this reliably.

Also, imagine the case where the client sends requestA on stream5; this arrives on the server where its processing takes time; the client times out, sends a RST_STREAM for stream5 (to cancel requestA) and then requestB on stream5. While these are in-flight, the server finishes the processing of requestA and sends the response for requestA on stream5. Now the client reads a response, but it does not know if it is that of requestA or that of requestB.

> But there is a finite number of streams available, so in theory, I could run out of streams and have to restart the connection.

That is correct. At 1 ms per exchange, it will take about 12 days to consume the stream ids for a single connection (`(2^31-1)/1000/3600/24/2=12.4` days) -- remember that stream ids are incremented by 2 (clients only send odd stream ids).
While this is possible, I have never encountered this case in all the HTTP/2 deployments that I have seen -- typically the connection goes idle and gets closed well before consuming all stream ids.

The specification preferred simplicity and stable features over the ability to reuse stream ids.

Also, bear in mind that HTTP/2 was designed mostly with the web in mind, where browsers make a number of requests to download a web page and its resources, but then stay idle for a while.

The case where an HTTP/2 connection is bombed with non-stop requests is definitely possible, but much rarer and as such it has not probably been deemed important enough in the design -- using 8 bytes for stream ids seems overkill and a cost that is paid for each request even if the 4 bytes limit is never, practically, reached.